# Estimate probabilites of a sum of independant binomial (with sizes fixed)

Tags: r, optimization, probability, estimation

I collect observations which are sum of K (**known** parameter) independant binomial variables with **known** number of trials but **unknown** probability of success:

The number of trials varies for each observations. Probabilities of success are constant all along observations but different for each binomial component of the sum.

Please find below a data simulation to explicit my issue:

Settings

```
# Probability of K=10 elementary binomial variables
prob <- c(0.002, 0.003, 0.008, 0.012, 0.008, 0.011, 0.005, 0.008, 0.002, 0.001)
# Number of observations
N <- 1000
```

Observations simulations

```
# Random size of binomials
X <- sample(1:200000, N*length(prob))
# Simulation of each elementary binomial variable (10) of each observation (1000)
Y <- mapply(rbinom, X, prob, n=1)
# The final observation is the sum of elementary ones
Y <- rowSums(matrix(Y, nrow=N))
```

Reshape numbers of trials

```
X <- matrix(X, nrow=N)
```

How to estimate `prob` only from `Y` and `X` ?

Comment: Yep, some math to do first.

Comment: Please tell us what `prob` represents.  If it's the *vector* of different probabilities, then you have ten separate estimates to make.  If it's not the vector, *then what is it?*

Comment: You say the probabilities of success are the same for all the components, if so, the sum is binomial also, so just use that.

Comment: @whuber yes `prob` is the vector of probabilities but you just observe the sum of realizations of the 10 binomials. We don't know the contribution of each component in `Y`.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen probabilities are different for each component (that's why `prob` contains 10 probabilities). They just do not change all along `N` observations

Comment: You can estimate the mean of `prob`.  You might also be able to estimate the variance of `prob`, but that's as far as you're going to get without having an astronomical number of observations; 1000 won't do.